# 'React/RCTConvert.h' file not found

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

We're trying to install `react-native-navigation` into our Expo 31 ejected app. We followed [the instructions](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing) but we're stuck with this issue:

[image]

More details [here](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4318).

Answer (score 0):

Go into (Project Name) -> Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths and add the directory that the file is located in. If you're still getting errors, make sure it's also set up in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries. Xcode just doesn't know where to look for that file yet.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: I added this to my Podfile.

```
 pod 'React',
:path => "../node_modules/react-native",
:subspecs => [
  "Core",
  "ART",
  "RCTActionSheet",
  "RCTAnimation",
  "RCTCameraRoll",
  "RCTGeolocation",
  "RCTImage",
  "RCTNetwork",
  "RCTText",
  "RCTVibration",
  "RCTWebSocket",
  "DevSupport",
  "CxxBridge"
]


pod 'yoga',
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"
pod 'DoubleConversion',
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
pod 'Folly',
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
pod 'glog',
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
```

The Long Answer:

I've been having the issue for the better part of the last year and I've struggled to find a good solution. However I think this one works.

The issue is that the file couldn't be found.

I first tried to redirect the paths like the following:

```
#import <React/{wherever the folder that file was located in}/FILE.h>
```

I found that this was an endless loop. There were too many to change. After a while, I figured the issue had to be with my Podfile. If the imports weren't being found, then it stand that there is likely an issue with the imports or the linking-- thus the Podfile.

In the [RN Docs troubleshooting section](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting) it mentions that

> If you are using CocoaPods, verify that you have added React along with the subspecs to the Podfile.

Unsure which ones to include, I found some help in the expo forums.

https://forums.expo.io/t/upgrading-to-sdk-26-pod-install-issue/8294

This issue has cost me a week, so I really hope some of you out there are able to use this. Thanks for reading!